# Keep state in parent and children components (Checkboxes and Checkbox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote *Checkbox* component, that receives an initial "checked" and keeps wether the checkbox is checked in it's state. It broadcast it's change through a `onChange` prop.

I have a *Checkboxes* component that renders many *Checkbox* components, it accepts a list of options and which ones should be checked, but this component also keep track of the checked checkboxes on its state.

It seems this makes the *Checkbox*'s own state obsolete, because its props change when *Checkboxes* re-renders based on its state. ***It all works***, but it feels like a code smell to me.

**Questions:**

1. Should I care that *Checkbox*'s state is no longer relevant? I could write this component to render only based on it's props, but I might use this component elsewhere, not inside of *Checkboxes*.
2. Is there a pattern or best practice I'm missing?
3. Does anybody sees a code smell here too?

```
const { useState, Fragment } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const Checkbox = ({
  label,
  value,
  checked: initialChecked,
  onChange,
}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(initialChecked);

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value, checked } }) => {
    setIsChecked(checked);
    onChange({ value, checked });
  };

  const id = `${name}_${value}`;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id={id}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={handleChange} />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{ label }</label>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


const Checkboxes = ({
  options,
  checked: initialChecked,
}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialChecked);
  const handleChange = ({ value, checked }) => {
    if (checked && !values.includes(value)) {
      setValues([...values, value]);
    } else if (!checked && values.includes(value)) {
      setValues([...values.filter((v) => v !== value)]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <Checkbox
          {...option}
          checked={values.includes(option.value)}
          onChange={handleChange} />
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  render(
    <Checkboxes
      options={[
        { label: 'Foo', name: 'selection', value: 'foo'},
        { label: 'Bar', name: 'selection', value: 'bar' }
      ]}
      checked={['bar']} />,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
});
```

Same code on Codepen: https://codepen.io/leonelgalan/pen/wvBYrOz?editors=0010

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: The main problem is having the `Checkboxes` component to group them all, I believe it shouldn't exist. Therefore, the `Checkbox` singular component needs to exists, but it will only use props from parent as source of truth. Which means that the state belongs to the parent.

Comment: If you feel like really need the `Checkboxes` component, you can, but it'll only consume props from a parent, and pass them down to each `Checkbox` you have. This is the idea, they are called stateless components. If you want some reference: https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/stateful-vs-stateless-react-components-13f647f7fc4

Comment: This is the simplified version, but the idea of *Checkboxes* is to group related check boxes: gender (male/female/other), age groups (13-19, 20-29, etc.) in a filter. It might have a "Clear" and "Apply" buttons. So it will do more than pass props to a Checkbox. I appreciate the reference material, it always good to learn more!